# Azure Kinect Viewer cannot start device on HP Elitedesk 800 OS:Win10

Tags: azurekinect

I installed Azure Kinect SDK successfully and it looks normal in Device Manager. But the Kinect Viewer cannot start the device. My machine is HP Elitedesk. OS version is Windows 10 (build version:18363). I tried on a Lenovo laptop and the Kinect Viewer works fine. So the device is not damaged. Anyone has pointer on what I can do to fix?

[Device Manager view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqHV8.png)
[Azure Kinect Viewer error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvnrP.png)

Log:

```
[ trace    ] : k4a_device_start_cameras(). k4a_device_start_cameras starting
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras(). Starting camera's with the following config.
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras().     color_format:3
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras().     color_resolution:1
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras().     depth_mode:2
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras().     camera_fps:2
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras().     synchronized_images_only:1
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras().     depth_delay_off_color_usec:0
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras().     wired_sync_mode:0
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras().     subordinate_delay_off_master_usec:0
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras().     disable_streaming_indicator:0
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=80000001, CmdLength=13, PayloadSize=0, CmdData=00000000 00000000...
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=000000e1, CmdLength=4, PayloadSize=0, CmdData=00000004 000001ec...
[ error    ] : depth_engine_start_helper(). Depth engine create and initialize failed with error code: 204.
[ error    ] : deresult == K4A_DEPTH_ENGINE_RESULT_SUCCEEDED returned failure in depth_engine_start_helper()
[ error    ] : depth_engine_start_helper(dewrapper, dewrapper->fps, dewrapper->depth_mode, &depth_engine_max_compute_time_ms, &depth_engine_output_buffer_size) returned failure in depth_engine_thread()
[ warning  ] : capturesync_add_capture(). Capture Error Detected, Depth 
[ info     ] : queue_stop(). Queue "Queue_capture" stopped, shutting down and notifying consumers.
[ info     ] : queue_stop(). Queue "Queue_depth" stopped, shutting down and notifying consumers.
[ info     ] : queue_stop(). Queue "Queue_color" stopped, shutting down and notifying consumers.
[ error    ] : dewrapper_start(). Depth Engine thread failed to start
[ error    ] : dewrapper_start(depth->dewrapper, config, depth->calibration_memory, depth->calibration_memory_size) returned failure in depth_start()
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=000000f2, PayloadSize=0
[ error    ] : cmd_status == CMD_STATUS_PASS returned failure in depthmcu_depth_stop_streaming()
[ error    ] : depthmcu_depth_stop_streaming(). ERROR: cmd_status=0x00000063
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=0000000a, PayloadSize=0
[ error    ] : depth_start(device->depth, config) returned failure in k4a_device_start_cameras()
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras(). k4a_device_start_cameras started
[ info     ] : k4a_device_stop_cameras(). k4a_device_stop_cameras stopping
[ info     ] : k4a_device_stop_cameras(). k4a_device_stop_cameras stopped
[ trace    ] : k4a_image_t_create(). Created   k4a_image_t 000001EC481A23E0
[ trace    ] : k4a_image_t_create(). Created   k4a_image_t 000001EC481A2660
[ trace    ] : k4a_image_t_create(). Created   k4a_image_t 000001EC481A2860
[ trace    ] : k4a_image_t_create(). Created   k4a_image_t 000001EC4821BE40
[ trace    ] : k4a_image_t_create(). Created   k4a_image_t 000001EC4821A0C0
[ trace    ] : k4a_image_t_create(). Created   k4a_image_t 000001EC4821B4C0
[ trace    ] : k4a_image_t_destroy(). Destroyed k4a_image_t 000001EC481A2660
[ trace    ] : k4a_image_t_destroy(). Destroyed k4a_image_t 000001EC481A23E0
[ trace    ] : k4a_image_t_destroy(). Destroyed k4a_image_t 000001EC4821BE40
[ trace    ] : k4a_image_t_destroy(). Destroyed k4a_image_t 000001EC481A2860
[ trace    ] : k4a_image_t_destroy(). Destroyed k4a_image_t 000001EC4821B4C0
[ trace    ] : k4a_image_t_destroy(). Destroyed k4a_image_t 000001EC4821A0C0
[ trace    ] : queue_t_destroy(). Destroyed queue_t 000001EC4A8A0B80
[ trace    ] : imu_t_destroy(). Destroyed imu_t 000001EC4820E470
[ trace    ] : color_t_destroy(). Destroyed color_t 000001EC48226D80
[ trace    ] : queue_t_destroy(). Destroyed queue_t 000001EC4A8A0860
[ trace    ] : dewrapper_t_destroy(). Destroyed dewrapper_t 000001EC481A19E0
[ trace    ] : depth_t_destroy(). Destroyed depth_t 000001EC481A5E00
[ trace    ] : queue_t_destroy(). Destroyed queue_t 000001EC4A8A0400
[ trace    ] : queue_t_destroy(). Destroyed queue_t 000001EC4A89FFA0
[ trace    ] : queue_t_destroy(). Destroyed queue_t 000001EC4A89FC30
[ trace    ] : capturesync_t_destroy(). Destroyed capturesync_t 000001EC481739D0
[ trace    ] : calibration_t_destroy(). Destroyed calibration_t 000001EC4519EBE0
[ trace    ] : usbcmd_t_destroy(). Destroyed usbcmd_t 000001EC4813C930
[ trace    ] : depthmcu_t_destroy(). Destroyed depthmcu_t 000001EC4A760320
[ trace    ] : usbcmd_t_destroy(). Destroyed usbcmd_t 000001EC4813CA10
[ trace    ] : colormcu_t_destroy(). Destroyed colormcu_t 000001EC481EE3B0
[ trace    ] : k4a_device_t_destroy(). Destroyed k4a_device_t 000001EC45109B40
[ trace    ] : k4a_device_t_create(). Created   k4a_device_t 000001EC4A7A7F60
[ trace    ] : depthmcu_t_create(). Created   depthmcu_t 000001EC4A7603A0
[ trace    ] : usbcmd_t_create(). Created   usbcmd_t 000001EC4813C930
[ info     ] : find_libusb_device(). Container ID found: {ccc11f1c-eddb-48c8-da9d-6c737eda8c49} 
[ info     ] : populate_serialnumber(). Serial Number found 000603501312
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=00000115, PayloadSize=255
[ trace    ] : colormcu_t_create(). Created   colormcu_t 000001EC481F36B0
[ trace    ] : usbcmd_t_create(). Created   usbcmd_t 000001EC4813D2D0
[ info     ] : find_libusb_device(). Container ID found: {ccc11f1c-eddb-48c8-da9d-6c737eda8c49} 
[ info     ] : populate_serialnumber(). Serial Number found 000603501312
[ trace    ] : calibration_t_create(). Created   calibration_t 000001EC479BB3D0
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=00000111, PayloadSize=10240
[ trace    ] : capturesync_t_create(). Created   capturesync_t 000001EC481739D0
[ trace    ] : queue_t_create(). Created   queue_t 000001EC4A89EC90
[ trace    ] : queue_t_create(). Created   queue_t 000001EC4A89ECE0
[ trace    ] : queue_t_create(). Created   queue_t 000001EC4A89EB00
[ trace    ] : depth_t_create(). Created   depth_t 000001EC481A4A00
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=00000201, PayloadSize=18
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=00000201, PayloadSize=18
[ critical ] : ******************** Device Info ********************
[ critical ] : K4A SDK version:     1.4.1
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=00000115, PayloadSize=255
[ critical ] : Serial Number:       000603501312
[ critical ] : RGB Sensor Version:  1.6.110
[ critical ] : Depth Sensor Version:1.6.79
[ critical ] : Mic Array Version:   1.6.14
[ critical ] : Sensor Config:       6109.7
[ critical ] : Build type:          Release
[ critical ] : Signature type:      MSFT
[ critical ] : ****************************************************
[ trace    ] : dewrapper_t_create(). Created   dewrapper_t 000001EC481A1E60
[ trace    ] : queue_t_create(). Created   queue_t 000001EC4A89EB50
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=000000f2, PayloadSize=0
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=0000000a, PayloadSize=0
[ trace    ] : color_t_create(). Created   color_t 000001EC4A88F6E0
[ trace    ] : imu_t_create(). Created   imu_t 000001EC4820E470
[ trace    ] : queue_t_create(). Created   queue_t 000001EC4A89F5A0
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=80000004, PayloadSize=0
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=00000115, PayloadSize=255
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=00000115, PayloadSize=255
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=80000006, PayloadSize=1
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=80000006, PayloadSize=1
[ trace    ] : k4a_device_start_cameras(). k4a_device_start_cameras starting
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras(). Starting camera's with the following config.
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras().     color_format:3
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras().     color_resolution:1
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras().     depth_mode:2
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras().     camera_fps:2
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras().     synchronized_images_only:1
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras().     depth_delay_off_color_usec:0
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras().     wired_sync_mode:0
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras().     subordinate_delay_off_master_usec:0
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras().     disable_streaming_indicator:0
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=80000001, CmdLength=13, PayloadSize=0, CmdData=00000000 00000000...
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=000000e1, CmdLength=4, PayloadSize=0, CmdData=00000004 000001ec...
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=00000022, CmdLength=4, PayloadSize=2000000, CmdData=00000002 000001ec...
[ error    ] : depth_engine_start_helper(). Depth engine create and initialize failed with error code: 204.
[ error    ] : deresult == K4A_DEPTH_ENGINE_RESULT_SUCCEEDED returned failure in depth_engine_start_helper()
[ error    ] : depth_engine_start_helper(dewrapper, dewrapper->fps, dewrapper->depth_mode, &depth_engine_max_compute_time_ms, &depth_engine_output_buffer_size) returned failure in depth_engine_thread()
[ warning  ] : capturesync_add_capture(). Capture Error Detected, Depth 
[ error    ] : dewrapper_start(). Depth Engine thread failed to start
[ info     ] : queue_stop(). Queue "Queue_capture" stopped, shutting down and notifying consumers.
[ info     ] : queue_stop(). Queue "Queue_depth" stopped, shutting down and notifying consumers.
[ info     ] : queue_stop(). Queue "Queue_color" stopped, shutting down and notifying consumers.
[ error    ] : dewrapper_start(depth->dewrapper, config, depth->calibration_memory, depth->calibration_memory_size) returned failure in depth_start()
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=000000f2, PayloadSize=0
[ error    ] : cmd_status == CMD_STATUS_PASS returned failure in depthmcu_depth_stop_streaming()
[ error    ] : depthmcu_depth_stop_streaming(). ERROR: cmd_status=0x00000063
[ trace    ] : usb_cmd_io(). XFR: Cmd=0000000a, PayloadSize=0
[ error    ] : depth_start(device->depth, config) returned failure in k4a_device_start_cameras()
[ info     ] : k4a_device_start_cameras(). k4a_device_start_cameras started
[ info     ] : k4a_device_stop_cameras(). k4a_device_stop_cameras stopping
[ info     ] : k4a_device_stop_cameras(). k4a_device_stop_cameras stopped
[ trace    ] : k4a_image_t_create(). Created   k4a_image_t 000001EC481A23E0
[ trace    ] : k4a_image_t_create(). Created   k4a_image_t 000001EC481A2660
[ trace    ] : k4a_image_t_create(). Created   k4a_image_t 000001EC481A2860
[ trace    ] : k4a_image_t_create(). Created   k4a_image_t 000001EC48218230
[ trace    ] : k4a_image_t_create(). Created   k4a_image_t 000001EC48219C30
[ trace    ] : k4a_image_t_create(). Created   k4a_image_t 000001EC48219DB0
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the remote access issue on Linux. See https://github.com/microsoft/Azure-Kinect-Sensor-SDK/issues/810.